# Remove prefix in taghelper-generated input tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

With a partial view containing this line

```
<input asp-for="Form.FirstName" asp- class="form-control" />
```

I get the following output

```
<input id="Form_FirstName" name="Form.FirstName" <!-- more stuff --> >
```

which means I need to account for that "Form" prefix in my action's definition using a Bind attribute like so

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendContactForm([Bind(Prefix = "Form")] ContactFormViewModel model)
```

I don't really like using the Bind attribute, I think it is very verbose and, being text-base, hard to maintain. I would much rather be able to tell the netcore2 `input` tag helper to simply omit the prefix when generating the HTML but I couldn't find any built-in solution but I might have missed it ...

I looked for inline tag helper attributes as well as attributes to add to my model but couldn't find anything ...

Is there any trick to remove this prefix or am I stuck with this (ugly) `Bind` ?

Comment: This also means that the antiforgery becomes prefixed (atleast in 2.1) which causes further issues.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation one option is to use a `<partial>` that contains your form and use the `model` attribute to pass your model in.

In your view this would be something like this.

```
<partial name="PartialName" model="@Model.Form">
```

In your partial, you would no longer need the prefix in your `asp-for` expressions.

```
<input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
```